# Размер блока вокруг изображения

Tags: html, css, css3

Почему блок `div`, созданный вокруг изображения, имеет высоту больше высоты изображения?

```
<div>
    <img src = "http://detkam.su/avatar/91/864925.jpeg"/>
</div>

div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cwb0z0bm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дефолтно, у `img` стоит `display: inline;`, что добавляет отступ из-за `line-height`.
Поставьте стиль `img {display: block; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Для дива нужно дать

```
font-size:0px;
```

Там наверное пробел появляется, если нет - поправьте.